# How is the octane percentage defined?

Tags: fuel, petrochemistry

Normally octane percentage is mentioned on petrol (95% octane). How is this defined? Is it percentage of chemical or some other parameters?

Comment: @Qmechanic Always wanted to learn about Hydrocarbon's in physics class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Wikipedia article on [octane rating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating). 95% octane is the same as an octane rating of 95, and it means the petrol has the same knocking characteristics as a mixture of 95% iso-octane and 5% heptane.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if the higher octane number  will it produce more energy? Or is it not even considered on octane indexing?

Comment: @sugunan: The amount of energy stored in the fuel is not related to the octane number. However a high octanc number allows the engine to use a higher compression ratio, and this increases the power output of the engine. So powerful engines tend to use high octance fuel, but only for its [knock resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_knocking), not because high octane fuels contain more energy.

Comment: Wow, only a 50% success rate in spelling *octane* :-)

Comment: I didn't get the point :S